# How could I remove sql server's table .mdf file's file_attribute_compressed attributes using C++ API function?

Tags: c++, sql-server

How could I remove sql server's table .mdf file's file_attribute_compressed attributes using C++ API functions so that these table .mdf file is not in compressed mode(blue color file). Therefore, sql server read/write these tables correctly. I found that if any file of Sql Server folder "DATA" become blue(which is compressed), program running sql server with that file will pop up a messagebox of "The file MDF is compressed but does not reside in a read-only database or filegroup. The file must be decompressed."

I tried to find the solution on the website and find one C++ API function call "SetFileAttributes", and I tried the way of adding or removing FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED but not effective so that .mdf file will not change the color from white to blue or blue to white.

Could you please suggestion any kind of effective C++ API function call so that I can remove the compress mode of these .mdf or .ldf file and sql server running without these above messagebox? Thank you very much for your help?
My running environment: Sql Server 2005 on Windows XP

code:

```
CString szFilePath = "E:\\DB.mdf";

DWORD dwFileAttributes = GetFileAttributes(szFilePath);

if ((dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED) == 0)

{

    SetFileAttributes(szFilePath, dwFileAttributes | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED);

    return;

}

if ((dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED)

{

    SetFileAttributes(szFilePath, dwFileAttributes & ~FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED);

    return;

}
```

Comment: Why bother with that? Simply don't place those files in an compressed drive or don't compress it to begin with.

Comment: Because programs that running some machines have this issue. We cannot set manually on each machine, so have to use API function call to remove compress mode of these .mdf files , could you suggest some effective programs to solve this issue before sql server mdf file corrupted?

Comment: You have a problem with your code, please *edit* your question and post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried so far.

Comment: already edited the code in the above, thank you

Comment: after this code, if DB.mdf has compress mode, it will remove the compress mode and become white color, if DB.mdf do not have compress mode, it will add the compress mode and become blue color. But things not like that. Could you tell me whats problem of this program?

Comment: The problem is that your first clause turns on compression.

Comment: No, even if the compress mode is on, it wont turn off in the second clause. I tried, the .mdf file color is not changed from blue to white. You can try this code.

Comment: What Roger is saying is true, you only need the second `if` statement. The first would turn compression on. What I am reading though in [SetFileAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation is that the minimum supported *Server* version is `Windows 2003`. Verify that you have the proper Operating System to run this function.

Comment: Also you are not checking the return value of `SetFileAttributes`. If it returns FALSE it failed. If SQL Server is running, it will block the files from being modified. Make sure that you STOP the SQL Server service before modifying anything on the file.

Comment: I tried to get the return value of SetFileAttributes and it always return TRUE. I found another way of using DeviceIoControl and FSCTL_SET_COMPRESSION on the website, but not sure whether this way is working or not. Could you suggest some effective ways to turn off the compression mode? Thanks

Comment: Help!!, I appreciate if anyone can help me:)